# OpenGL How to create better 3D models?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Right now I'm trying to create a helix in OpenGL, and I have successfully created a helix with a line. But this isn't so detailed... so I made some google searches and figured I could make my line with triangles instead.

So I was wondering, if we take my helix as an example, if this suggestion means calculating all the positions of the triangles for my helix, or does it mean I should use some 3D program like... blender, Maya etc. to create the models and import them into OpenGL?

Comment: That depends on a few things. Is the helix or camera moving? Is the helix going to be like a ribbon or a tube? Is it going to be textured? Is it going to have 3D lighting applied to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a [parametric equation for your helix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Helix.html):

```
x(t) = r*cos(t)
y(t) = r*sin(t)
z(t) = c*t
```

Then you are sampling `t` and connecting successive points with lines.

The next step to form a mesh (ribbon or tube) is to create a [Frenet Frame](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~blob/courses/305/notes/pdf/ref-frames.pdf) for each sample. The derivatives `(x'(t),y'(t),z'(t))` (the velocity component `V`)
will give you one axis and the second derivatives `(x''(t),y''(t),z''(t))` will give you another axis (the acceleration component `A`). Perform a cross product to get a third axis and orthonormalize your axis vectors to get the coordinate system attached to a point.
If you are modeling the shape with a "tube," then you define the cross section of the tube in this coordinate system and connect corresponding cross section points to form the mesh:

[image]

If you are just using a ribbon then its easier -- just use the A axis for your cross section and connect the point to form the mesh:

[image]

The derivate vector `V` is

```
   x'(t) = r*sin(t)
   y'(t) = -r*cos(t)
   z'(t) = c
```

The second derivative vector `A` is

```
   x''(t) = -r*cos(t)
   y''(t) = -r*sin(t)
   z''(t) = 0
```

The math you want to orthonormalize your coordinate system:

```
   normalize(A)
   AxV = cross(A,V)
   normalize(AxV)
   V = cross(AxV,A)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I got the Frenet Frame working. I had to increase the z value according to some value I choose myself though. But it works :)

Comment: @WYS sweet. I am glad I made sense.